# Can Flink OutputTag be reused?

Tags: java, apache-flink

In Flink, when we have two or more operators which are side outputing the same data type of records, can we reuse the OutputTag that data output data type?

Example:

```
OutputTag<A> sideOutputTag = new OutputTag<A>("side-output") {};
ProcessFunction1 processFunction1 = new ProcessFunction1(sideOutputTag);
ProcessFunction2 processFunction2 = new ProcessFunction2(sideOutputTag);

SingleOutputStreamOperator<A> output1 = input.process(processFunction1).getSideOutput(sideOutputTag);

SingleOutputStreamOperator<A> output2 = input.process(processFunction2).getSideOutput(sideOutputTag);
```

In this approach, will `output1` contains the outputs processed by `processFunction2`?
Or, will `output1` and `output2` contain the records processed by `processFunction1` and `processFunction2` separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse the same tag, and the resulting streams will be distinct. For example:

```java
final OutputTag<String> errors = new OutputTag<String>("errors"){};

SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> task1 = ...;
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> task2 = ...;
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> task3 = ...;

DataStream<String> exceptions1 = task1.getSideOutput(errors);
DataStream<String> exceptions2 = task2.getSideOutput(errors);
DataStream<String> exceptions3 = task3.getSideOutput(errors);

DataStream<String> exceptions = exceptions1.union(exceptions2, exceptions3);

exceptions.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer(...));
```